# Symbol's function definition is void: declare-function

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

New to emacs. GNU Emacs 22.1.1 on OSX.
Installed evil as per instructions. I get:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: declare-function

emacs --debug-init gives:

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function declare-function)  
  (declare-function evil-visual-state-p "evil-visual")  
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<3>> nil "/Users/rahul/.emacs.d  /evil/evil-repeat.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer pos$  
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/rahul/.emacs.d/evil/evil-  repeat.el" "/Users/rahul/.emacs.d/evil/evil-repeat.el$  
  require(evil-repeat)  
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "/Users/rahul/.emacs.d  /evil/evil.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1$  
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/rahul/.emacs.d/evil/evil.el"   "/Users/rahul/.emacs.d/evil/evil.el" nil t)  
  require(evil)  
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/rahul/.emacs" nil t)    ; Reading at buffer position 122  
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/rahul/.emacs"   
"/Users/rahul/.emacs" t t)  
  load("~/.emacs" t t)  
  #[nil "^H\205\276^@   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202A^@ \311=\2033^@\312\307\313\314#\203#^@\315\202A^@\312\307\31$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

My .emacs has:

```
;;; Emacs Load Path  
(setq load-path (cons "~/bin" load-path))  

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/evil")  
(require 'evil)    
(evil-mode 1)  
(require 'undo-tree)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Emacs 22.1 is now old (mid-2007). You want either the latest 23.x or the latest 24.x pre-test from http://emacsformacosx.com/