# emacs: Symbol's function definition is void: loop

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

I am testing on loading packages in emacs `init.el` (Emacs 24.3). I followed [a blog](http://batsov.com/articles/2012/02/19/package-management-in-emacs-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/)  by the author of `emacs prelude` to automatically load packages, and copied the code there into my `init.el` as in the bottom. However, I got an error message about the `loop` function/symbol, which says:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: loop
```

Can someone please explain how to fix the code?

I've searched around on the internet, and it seems that `loop` is a macro in `cl-lib`. My guess is that the definition for `loop` is missing, and I attempted to fix the problem by adding `(require 'cl-lib)`, as shown in the code, but the error remains. There are other SO questions on similar error messages, e.g.: [ELisp: cl-loop for "Symbol's value as variable is void"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871056/elisp-cl-loop-for-symbols-value-as-variable-is-void), [Symbol's function definition is void: declare-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831400/symbols-function-definition-is-void-declare-function). But the error messages are different on what's missing, and the answers mostly suggest alternative routes, such as using newer version of emacs.

-- code --

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

;;; check & load packages
(defvar prelude-packages
  '( haskell-mode )
  "A list of packages to ensure are installed at launch.")

;;(require 'cl-lib) ;debug
(defun prelude-packages-installed-p ()
  (loop for p in prelude-packages
        when (not (package-installed-p p)) do (return nil)
        finally (return t)))

(unless (prelude-packages-installed-p)
  ;; check for new packages (package versions)
  (message "%s" "Emacs Prelude is now refreshing its package database...")
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (message "%s" " done.")
  ;; install the missing packages
  (dolist (p prelude-packages)
    (when (not (package-installed-p p))
      (package-install p))))

(provide 'prelude-packages)
;;; end load packages
```

Comment: This may help: (Emacs 24.3.1):  loop is an alias for `cl-loop' in `cl.el'.   And
cl-loop is a Lisp macro in `cl-macs.el'.  Do C-h f loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `cl-lib` package was introduced in Emacs 24.3, and provides a number of Common Lisp features, all with the `cl-` prefix.  Before that, the only way to use those features was to require the `cl` library, and use unprefixed names, e.g. `loop` instead of `cl-loop`.  However, that was discouraged because of the possibility for name conflicts, and it's usually recommended to use the prefixed names if possible.

Since you are using Emacs 24.3, the "correct" way to fix this would be to  replace `loop` with `cl-loop` and `return` with `cl-return`:

```
(defun prelude-packages-installed-p ()
  (cl-loop for p in prelude-packages
           when (not (package-installed-p p)) do (cl-return nil)
           finally (cl-return t)))
```

(You don't need `(require 'cl-lib)`, because `cl-loop` and `cl-return` are autoloaded.)

Alternatively, you could add `(require 'cl)` to get access to the unprefixed names, and leave the code as it is.  This will also work on earlier Emacs versions.

---

I can't help noticing that this function could be written more succinctly:

```
(defun prelude-packages-installed-p ()
  (cl-every 'package-installed-p prelude-packages))
```

The same issue about `cl-every` plus `cl-lib` vs `every` plus `cl` applies.

Comment: I had to require cl-lib to get cl-every to work in emacs 24.5.1